Problem with Linq query to an Entity Framework Core / .NET Core 7.0 in VB.NET
I'm trying to make an easy query with my Entity Framework Core / .NET Core 7.0 in VB.NET:
Public Function GetOneRecord(idOne As Long, idTwo As Long) As Reply(Of Object)

    Dim reply As New Reply(Of Object)

    Try

        reply.obj = db.Table.
            Include("AnotherTable1").
            Include("AnotherTable1.AnotherTable2").AsNoTracking().
            Where(Function(a) a.SomeId = idOne AndAlso a.SomeIdTwo = idTwo).FirstOrDefault()

        If (Not reply.obj Is Nothing) Then

            reply.ok = True
            ' Everything its Ok

        Else

            reply.ToError("Couldn't find the record...")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        reply.ToError("Couldn't get the records correctly...")
    End Try

    Return reply

End Function

The query is working fine, every time I call that function, it works fine, the problem is that sometimes, the function returned

Couldn't find the record...

It means, the record was not found, but is the same record I'm calling like 20-30 times before the code return it couldn't find it.
So every 20 to 30 times (sometimes more, sometimes less), I try to get some record, it works fine but then, some of the callings just don't get the record.
What should I do to fix this?
I don't even know what the problem is, because the record does exist, and the function returned me the record correctly, it's just one spontaneous query that did not "find" it.
This is happening to me with only this function, I'm not seeing this error with another function or query to the database (with my SQL Server and it fails with my Azure database too, so it's not a database problem).
I'm getting all the database model with a Scaffold-DbContext command on the console.
Sorry if my English is not good enough:/
I don't know what to do, this error is just spontaneous...

Do you have any error displayed in the Output of your editor ?

You are checking the equality of two longs against your db fields, idOne and idTwo, which the db can do very efficiently. You don't need to short-circuit with AndAlso, instead just use And. It's adding unnecessary complexity to your query. Don't know if this will solve it but give it a try.

@FolabiAhn That's the thing, there's no error, my validation "If (Not reply.obj Is Nothing) Then" just enter in the ELSE, because the object is NULL, in that moment, the record was "not found", but if i just call that function again, it will return me the correctly record, like i said, it is spontaneous, so i don't really know what the problem is

@djv actually i was looking about And and AndAlso and the info just recomended that using AndAlso in querys to database, is useful than And, because "And "need to validate every condition to consider if everything its ok to make it a TRUE condition for the IF, meanwhile the AndAlso consider every condition while processing the conditions, so, if some of the condition is FALSE, it just throw the ELSE instead of validate the other conditions to check if ALL the conditions were true
In this case, i don't think this is the problem, because i use this in all my querys and just this one fail

@JosuéDavidAlpizarCruz need to validate every condition is extremely efficient in a relational database, with your case being almost the simplest. Short-circuiting in SQL is not supported, and the equivalent query would involve perhaps a case statement, vs simply AND. You have an intermittent issue. These can be very difficult to diagnose, as you might expect a deterministic outcome, but you aren't getting it. Try anything suggested. That's my recommendation.
